# Porque el codigo solo devuelve PERDISTE?

Tags: python

Tengo este pequeño programa que monte para practicar de Piedra, papel o tijera pero me devuelve siempre el resultado PERDISTE, no cae en ninguna de las otras condicionales aunque se cumplan. Si por ejemplo se cumple la condicional GANASTE igualmente me muestra PERDISTE en todos los casos.

```
import random

def eleccion_jugador():
    jugador = int(input("Dime un numero 1, 2 o 3: "))
    if jugador == 1:
        return "Elegiste piedra"
    elif jugador == 2:
        return "Elegiste papel"
    else:
        return "Elegiste tijera"
print(eleccion_jugador())
        
def eleccion_computadora():
    computadora = random.randint(1, 3)
    if computadora == 1:
        return "La computadora eligio piedra"
    elif computadora == 2:
        return "La computadora eligio papel"
    else:
        return "La computadora eligio tijera"
print(eleccion_computadora())
    
    
def combate(eleccion_jugador, eleccion_computadora):
    if (eleccion_jugador == 1 and eleccion_computadora == 3) or (eleccion_jugador == 2 and eleccion_computadora == 1) or (eleccion_jugador == 3 and eleccion_computadora == 2):
        return "GANASTE"
    elif eleccion_jugador == eleccion_computadora:
        return "EMPATASTE"
    else:
        return "PERDISTE"

print(combate(eleccion_jugador, eleccion_computadora))
```

Comment: `eleccion_jugador` y `eleccion_computadores` son funciones, no enteros. Nunca serán iguales.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en que operas con `eleccion_jugador` y `eleccion_computadora`, que son **funciones**. Una función nunca será igual a otra ni tampoco es comparable con un entero.

Las funciones que usas tampoco retornan valores, por lo que la jugada de cada cual se pierde.

He aqui una solución más sencilla, sin usar funciones:

```
import random

movidas = ['', 'piedra', 'papel', 'tijeras']
jugador = int(input("Dime un numero 1, 2 o 3: "))
print(f"Elegiste {movidas[jugador]}")

computadora = random.randint(1, 3)
print(f"La computadora elegio {movidas[computadora]}")

if (jugador == 1 and computadora == 3) or (
        jugador == 2 and computadora == 1) or (
        jugador == 3 and computadora == 2):
    print("GANASTE")
elif jugador == computadora:
    print("EMPATASTE")
else:
    print("PERDISTE")
```

produce:

```
Dime un numero 1, 2 o 3: 2
Elegiste papel
La computadora elegio papel
EMPATASTE

Process finished with exit code 0
```